# Apt-get retries download endlessly

Tags: installation, apt, virtualbox

May be I am putting this wrong. I have this problem: for some packages apt-get retries download endlessly (but does not get stuck), like this:

```
Need to get 19.3 MB/20.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 28.7 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
Get:1 http://mirrors.cat.pdx.edu/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main linux-firmware all 1.95.1 [19.3 MB]
Get:2 http://mirrors.cat.pdx.edu/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main linux-firmware all 1.95.1 [19.3 MB]
Get:3 http://mirrors.cat.pdx.edu/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main linux-firmware all 1.95.1 [19.3 MB]
Get:4 http://mirrors.cat.pdx.edu/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main linux-firmware all 1.95.1 [19.3 MB]
Get:5 http://mirrors.cat.pdx.edu/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main linux-firmware all 1.95.1 [19.3 MB]
```

It is able to complete the download, but keeps on retrying to get linux-firmware forever. Hitting Ctrl-C works, but I can not complete the upgrade. The same thing happens with some other packages (for example openjdk-7-jre-headless).

I am using a VirtualBox VM and I can download those packages from a browser, but it takes very long to complete the download (some sort of network connectivity issue). I get a decent connection to the mirror though.

Is there a fix or workaround for this?

Comment: try changing your mirror from software sources.

Comment: I did, that does not help: same behavior on slow and fast mirrors

Comment: Try installing Squid on another VM, attaching both VMs to the same host-only network, and finally adding the proxy to /etc/apt/apt.conf

Comment: I set it up using avahi, but the result is the same. Is there a way to check that it is functioning the way it should?

Comment: I installed Squid on the host and configured apt-get to use it; then I tried to download the very same things that apt-get failed to get. And it turned out to be an issue with my Windows 7 host -- I could not fetch those packages in it. The workaround was to get the packages using a separate Linux box and feed apt with them by putting in /var/cache/apt/archives/

Answer (score 1):

It was an issue with the host system, it was unable to download the `offending' packages.

I got the URLs that apt-get was requesting through Squid proxy on the host. Then I tried to fetching them by hand on the host and the download failed -- not sure why.

Moral: always check that the host is able to get the update.

The workaround is to use a separate machine to get the packages (only the ones you are unable to get in VM), verifying that they can be opened, and then putting them in /var/cache/apt/archives, so apt-get can grab them.